# How to create a recurrent neural network in tensor flow for variable sequence length?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying the create a recurrent neural network in tensor flow. The input to the network is a sequence of vectors. The sequence length is different for all the inputs. I want to do this with batch of inputs.

Can anyone help me on how exactly to do this? I have gone through the tutorials on the tensorflow site, but it is still not clear to me.

Comment: This https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/models/rnn model does what you want (for ranslation in this case)

Comment: Hi Ashish, I tried to go through that code before asking this question. But i couldn't figure out exactly how is it doing? Do you mind pointing to the right place in the code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the rnn function defined [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py#L35)

One of the arguments it takes is sequence_length

> sequence_length: Specifies the length of each sequence in inputs.
>         An int32 or int64 vector (tensor) size [batch_size].  Values in [0, T).

Here is how to implement complete loop

```
# x, state, sequence_length are placeholders
outputs, final_state = tf.nn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, state, sequence_length = sequence_lengths)
# add softmax layer, define loss, training method, etc
...

# code for one epoch
iterations = total_data_length / batch_size
max_sequence_length = max(all_possible_sequence_lengths)
cur_state = initial_state

for i in range(iterations):
    # x is of dimension [max_sequence_length, batch_size, input_size]
    # sequence_lengths is of dimension [batch_size]
    x_data, sequence_data, y_data = mini_batch(batch_size)

    feed_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip(x, x_data)}
    feed_dict.append(sequence_lengths: sequence_data, ...)
    outs, cur_state, _ = session.run([outputs, final_state, train], feed_dict)
```

This method was bit confusing to me for couple of reasons:

1. Input shape is [sequence_length, batch_size, input_size] and not [batch_size, sequence_length, input_size]. However, this totally makes sense if you go through the code and see how rnn() is implemented. This also means you need to reshape your outputs (having dimension same as inputs) in order to pass them to matmul and then softmax for example.
2. Parameter inputs in function rnn() is a python list. And you cannot pass this in feed_dict as {x: x_data}, you will get an error saying "Not able to hash type: 'list'". Instead see how i used comprehension in code above.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your data set, but you can do:

1. Use the max length in your dataset, or
2. Use a reasonable size (e.g., 256) and splits the input data up to the size if they are longer than the size.